# Does not contain requested field: optional double

Tags: hive

I am facing weird issue with selecting the data from Hive external table.

Data is unloaded form SQL Server in parquet file format and all other fields except one (which is amount field and been cast to float) in SQL Server select clause are "string" fields.

*select

cast(field_1 as float) as field_1,

field_2,

field_3

from table;*

Hive DDL-

*create external table hive_tbl_1 (

field_1 float,

field_2 string,

field_3 string

)

PARTITIONED BY (data_date string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT

'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT

'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'

LOCATION

'hdfs://mypath/data/file1/20181220'

TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='GZIP')*

When i am selecting the data from this table, it throws error-

"does not contain requested field: optional double field_1"

Please note all other tables are working fine and able to show data as long as the fields are "cast" to "varchar" in select statement and created as "string" in Hive DDL. i tried other numeric types as well, all seem to have issues in Hive.

Why float type is creating this issue and how to fix it? After all, we can't really always cast all the fields to "varchar" and that won;t produce the right result as well in many business scenarios.

Comment: experts, anyone have an idea on it?

Comment: How were your files created and whats your hive version?  I face this problem as well and my files were created by fastparquet python library .

Comment: Hi Prasannads, seems to be the same case for me, it is using fastparquet to write the parquet file. Did you find the fix though? Thanks!

Comment: No , but you can use pyarrow library to create parquet files . In my case , i cannot use it .